# People picker not able to resolve users stored in sdf file on identity server

Tags: sharepoint

I am into a serious trouble any help is appreciated.
I have a SharePoint2013 site.Authentication is done using ADFS and think texture identity server configured on a different server(not on the server which has sharepoint installed).Now users are able to log into sharepoint site but when I search them in people picker no user is shown.I searched on net and found that I have to develop a custom claim provider.I have done that but now people picker is showing AD users but in my case users are stored in an sdf file of identity server can anybody please explain how I can develop a CCP which can query this sdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much of this will be helpful for you, but you should take a look at the custom claim set up - instead of pointing to AD it should point to your user list.